# How to solve a transitive closure question?

Tags: matrices

If $r=\{ (1,3),(2,1),(3,4),(4,2)\}$ then which one of the following matrices is the adjacency matrix of $r^{+}$, the transitive closure of $r$?
Select one:

a. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
b. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
c. \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
d. \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
e. \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}

Could you please explain the how today create adjacency matrix for this question? I am aware that the answer is b. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the transitive closure of $r$?

Comment: I am not sure I did the adjacency matrix calculation and got  e for my answer which I know is incorrect, any further details on how to approach this would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Transitive closure of a relation $r$ is the smallest transitive relation that contains $r$. One forms a transitive relation of $r$ by adding a pair $(a, c)$ in $r$ whenever the pairs $(a, b)$ and $(b, c)$ belong to $r$. We keep on doing this until it is not possible to add further any other pairs. In this problem, I can add the pair $(1, 4)$ to $r$ because $(1, 3), (3, 4)$ belongs to $r$. So $r$ is updated as $$r=\{ (1,3),(2,1),(3,4),(4,2), (1, 4)\}.$$ By same reasoning I can add $(4, 1)$ and repeating this process, $r^+$ turns out to be $A\times A$ where $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Now the adjacency matrix of $A\times A$ is b.

Comment: Thanks so does that mean {1, 1} and {2, 2} can exist as well?

Comment: Yes they will as you continue the process.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the pairs of $r$ describe a cyclic permutation of the vertices of the graph. This means that every vertex can eventually be reached from any other, so the transitive closure is the complete graph with four vertices. The corresponding adjacency matrix should be obvious at this point.